# How can i know an application running in debug or run mode in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

I do start/stop my application more than 15 to 20 times every day. Every time i start app in debug mode only. But some times the debug(break points) would not work, then i will get confuse that is my app running in debug or run mode.

Do you have any idea to find out.

Even some times, I started my app in debug mode and it runs in debug mode for some time, suddenly works as run mode, it would not consider my break points. so, if i restart my app in debug mode only, i can do debug again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the application is running, open the Debug view in Eclipse. If all that you see in the tree is a path to your Java distribution under the project name then you are in run mode. If you are in debug mode then you will see the above information plus all the threads that are currently running in your application.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch your application, the mode into which it runs is indicated in the "server" panel, like this :
[image]

or 
 [image]

Sometimes, when the debug mode doesn't work(for example it can't start), I remove all the break points, then I set them again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure what you run 1st. 
Debug mode should display you code with variables in debug tab in eclipse while program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application a standalone application or a server hosted application which you remote debug? In both cases as soon as the debugger is connected to whatever local or remote process the signs left to your debuger icon get enabled. Those are in a row a few arrows (Step back, Step into, Step over) a green Arrow for Resume, a Suspend Icon, one for Stop and one for Disconnect.

If you open the debug View (Window->Show View->Other... type in "Debug") you should as well see if your Debugger is currently connected to any process.